# Facing AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have posted my sample train data as well as test data along with my code. I'm trying to use Naive Bayes algorithm to train the model.

But, in the reviews I'm getting list of list. So, I think my code is failing with the following error:

```
return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Can anyone of you please help me out regarding the same as I'm new to python ....

## train.txt:

```
review,label
Colors & clarity is superb,positive
Sadly the picture is not nearly as clear or bright as my 40 inch Samsung,negative
```

## test.txt:

```
review,label
The picture is clear and beautiful,positive
Picture is not clear,negative
```

## My code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

def load_data(filename):

    reviews = list()
    labels = list()
    with open(filename) as file:
        file.readline()
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            labels.append(line[1])
            reviews.append(line[0].split())


    return reviews, labels

X_train, y_train = load_data('/Users/7000015504/Desktop/Sep_10/sample_train.csv')
X_test, y_test = load_data('/Users/7000015504/Desktop/Sep_10/sample_test.csv')


clf = CountVectorizer()
X_train_one_hot =  clf.fit(X_train)
X_test_one_hot = clf.transform(X_test)

bnbc = BernoulliNB(binarize=None)
bnbc.fit(X_train_one_hot, y_train)

score = bnbc.score(X_test_one_hot, y_test)
print("score of Naive Bayes algo is :" , score)
```

Comment: `lower()` is not an attribute of a `list`. Try converting it to a `numpy` array. Then `.lower()` should work.

Comment: where is `return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())` in your code ?

Comment: That's an easy piece of code.  You can manage it by your own ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have applied a few modifications to your code. The one posted below works; I added comments on how to debug the one you posted above.

```
# These three will not used, do not import them
# from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer 
# from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
# from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

# This performs the classification task that you want with your input data in the format provided
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB 

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

def load_data(filename):
    """ This function works, but you have to modify the second-to-last line from
    reviews.append(line[0].split()) to reviews.append(line[0]).
    CountVectorizer will perform the splits by itself as it sees fit, trust him :)"""
    reviews = list()
    labels = list()
    with open(filename) as file:
        file.readline()
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            labels.append(line[1])
            reviews.append(line[0])

    return reviews, labels

X_train, y_train = load_data('train.txt')
X_test, y_test = load_data('test.txt')

vec = CountVectorizer() 
# Notice: clf means classifier, not vectorizer. 
# While it is syntactically correct, it's bad practice to give misleading names to your objects. 
# Replace "clf" with "vec" or something similar.

# Important! you called only the fit method, but did not transform the data 
# afterwards. The fit method does not return the transformed data by itself. You 
# either have to call .fit() and then .transform() on your training data, or just fit_transform() once.

X_train_transformed =  vec.fit_transform(X_train) 

X_test_transformed = vec.transform(X_test)

clf= MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X_train_transformed, y_train)

score = clf.score(X_test_transformed, y_test)
print("score of Naive Bayes algo is :" , score)
```

The output of this code is:

```
score of Naive Bayes algo is : 0.5
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel R. How can we calculate precision and recall ?

Comment: Mhmh, it seems that the data in this format allows to compute confusion_matrix from sklearn.metrics, but neither precision_score or recall_score. I'll look into it, but for now you can print the confusion matrix and compute them manually from there, by adding:

`y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_transformed)`
`from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix`
`print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))`

Comment: Edit: I made it work. The parameter `pos_label='positive'` must be passed to the precision_score function as follows:

`y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_transformed)`
`from sklearn.metrics import precision_score`
`print(precision_score(y_test,y_pred,pos_label='positive'))`

Comment: R, I've tried using your above edited code. But I have faced with the error:     "choose another average setting." % y_type)
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting.

Comment: So, I have changed precision_score and recall_score by replacing  attribute pos_label='positive'  with average='micro'.      print("Precision Score : ",precision_score(y_test,y_pred,average='micro'))
print("Recall Score :" , recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro') )

Comment: But, I'm getting same score for accuracy, precision and recall. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through each and every element in the list.

```
for item in list():
      item = item.lower()
```

Note : Only applicable if you iterate through a list of string ( dtype = str ) .

Comment: Can you please edit my code over here. Since, I'm a newbie to python. reviews contains list of list