# How to implement Naive Bayes algorithm using "onehot_enc"?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have followed this [site](https://medium.com/nlpython/sentiment-analysis-analysis-ee5da4448e37) to use Naive Bayes algorithm for my dataset. Here the dataset is split into two files, one is review.txt and the other is label.txt. And I have used "train_test_split" function over here.

## My code :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

with open("/Users/abc/review.txt") as f:
    reviews = f.read().split("\n")
with open("/Users/abc/label.txt") as f:
    labels = f.read().split("\n")

reviews_tokens = [review.split() for review in reviews]

onehot_enc = MultiLabelBinarizer()
onehot_enc.fit(reviews_tokens)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(reviews_tokens, labels, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)


bnbc = BernoulliNB(binarize=None)
bnbc.fit(onehot_enc.transform(X_train), y_train)

score = bnbc.score(onehot_enc.transform(X_test), y_test)
print("score of Naive Bayes algo is :" , score)

predicted_y = bnbc.predict(onehot_enc.transform(X_test))
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted_y).ravel()
precision_score = tp / (tp + fp)
recall_score = tp / (tp + fn)

print("precision_score :" , precision_score)
print("recall_score :" , recall_score)
```

But, now in my requirement has the dataset in the single file(review,label). And I need to manually provide test and train data separately. So, implemented the code accordingly.

But, I'm unable to use "onehot_enc" here. It is throwing errors, since the reviews which is returned from "load_data" function is a list of list of words.

Can anyone suggest me how to implement my code using "onehot_enc" for my dataset ...

So, for this I have used the below code:

## train_data.csv:

```
review,label
Colors & clarity is superb,positive
Sadly the picture is not nearly as clear or bright as my 40 inch Samsung,negative
```

## test_data.csv:

```
review,label
The picture is clear and beautiful,positive
Picture is not clear,negative
```

## New Code: (Supplying reviews,labels in a single csv file)

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score


def load_data(filename):
    reviews = list()
    labels = list()
    with open(filename) as file:
        file.readline()
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            labels.append(line[1])
            reviews.append(line[0])

    return reviews, labels

X_train, y_train = load_data('/Users/abc/train_data.csv')
X_test, y_test = load_data('/Users/abc/test_data.csv')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252107/facing-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-lower/52252552). The snippets from the two csv files are identical, and the problem description is very similar as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you want is to tokenize your reviews to use Naive Bayes. 
One hot encoding is for labels or categorical data.

**You should use it on your labels to have 0 and 1 instead of positive and negative but not on your reviews**

For your text, there are functions built in sklearn to tokenize, typically [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer) will probably work here.

I suggest to look at the [follwing link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) which explains how to work with text in detail.

Comment: But, in the website which I have mentioned, they have used One hot encoding on review_tokens. Using One hot encoding that I'm getting 90% accuracy and using CountVectorizer , I'm getting 49% accuracy.